# General formula for a polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

I have the following table which is the tabulation of coefficients of polynomial series:
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 9 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 72 & 0 & 24 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 225 & 0 & 600 & 0 & 120 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 4050 & 0 & 5400 & 0 & 720 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 11025 & 0 & 66150 & 0 & 52920 & 0 & 5040 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 352800 & 0 & 1058400 & 0 & 564480 & 0 & 40320 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 893025 & 0 & 9525600 & 0 & 17146080 & 0 & 6531840 & 0 & 362880 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 44651250 & 0 & 238140000 & 0 & 285768000 & 0 & 81648000 & 0 & 3628800 & 0 & 0 \\
 108056025 & 0 & 1800933750 & 0 & 5762988000 & 0 & 4939704000 & 0 & 1097712000 & 0 & 39916800 & 0 \\
 0 & 7780033800 & 0 & 64833615000 & 0 & 138311712000 & 0 & 88914672000 & 0 & 15807052800 & 0 & 479001600 \\
\end{array}

Columns are powers of the variable, starting at 0, so first column is $x^0$, second is $x^1$, and so on. Rows are successive iterations of the polynomial series, row 1 is $n=1$, row 2 is $n=2$, and so on. How can I find a general formula for the polynomial series?

Comment: Only a partial answer but the leading coefficient is always $n!$. $p_1(x)=1!x^0$, $p_2(x)=2!x^1$, $p_3(x)=9+3!x^2$ and so on.

Comment: And the free coefficient is 0 or ((2 n + 1)!!)^2.